# First historical references on auto-correlation and cross-correlation

Tags: correlation, references, autocorrelation, cross-correlation, history

Although the origin of Pearson's correlation coefficient is well documented ([see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient)), I have trouble to find some of the first and historical papers introducing the motivation, the benefits and the opportunity of Pearson's autocorrelation and cross-correlation in the domain of time-series analysis.

I guess that these papers would coincide with the beginning of time-series analysis itself, which is my general purpose of interest. Any useful reference for reconstructing this history is welcome.